# C: Weird Printing Error?

Tags: c

I don't understand how this works. Say I have the following:

```
void print(char* str, int len)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if (str[i]=='\0')
            printf(" ");
        else
            printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

char* sym4 = "=";
char str2[strlen(var)+strlen(sym4)];

unsigned long temp1 = 0x00000008;
unsigned char* nTableSize = (unsigned char*)&temp1;

memcpy(str2, var, strlen(var));
memcpy(str2+strlen(var), sym4, 1);
memcpy(str2+strlen(var)+1, nTableSize, 4);

print(str2, 5);
print(str2, 6);
```

and running it gives the output:

```
var=
var
```

so evidently something is going wrong (plus it's messing the rest of my program up). Why isn't nTableSize being correctly copied to str2 in such a way that printing 5 characters results in a different output from 6?...

Comment: `memcpy(str2+strlen(var)+1, nTableSize, 4);` is going out of bounds.

Comment: How is it going out of bounds?

Comment: It's only big enough for `strlen(var) + 1` characters, but you're copying that many, and then 4 more.

Comment: *facepalm* Thanks. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Hold on; i corrected it to 4 more characters and I get the same result?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on a little-endian architecture like x86 or x86-64, the 4-byte value 0x0000008 is represented in memory as the bytes `08 00 00 00`.  You're printing out the bytes as characters, and character 8 is ASCII for the backspace character `'\b'`.

When you print out a `\b` to the terminal, the terminal driver moves the cursor one character backwards, but it doesn't actually write anything out—it's not until you write the next character which causes it to overwrite the character that was previously there.

So, when you print out the 5 bytes `"var=\b"`, it prints out `"var="` and leaves the cursor under the `=` sign.  But when you print out the 6 bytes `"var=\b "`, it writes `"var="`, moves the cursor back one, and overwrites the `=` with a space, leaving you with `"var "`.

If you redirected the output to a file instead of printing to the terminal, you'd see the raw `08` byte being printed instead.